# Angular universal on existing project

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

So i followed this [article](https://medium.com/@nilesh93.j/enabling-server-side-rendering-on-an-existing-angular-application-with-angular-universal-5fdf7549b928) implementing SSR on a pre existing angular 5 project and encountered these issues when i ran the command

> ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./server.ts

This is the output in my console

```
ce0@ce0 ~/Documents/Angular/exampleSSR $ ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./server.ts

/home/ce0/Documents/Angular/exampleSSR/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:300
    throw new TSError(formatDiagnostics(diagnosticList, cwd, ts, lineOffset))
          ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
Cannot find type definition file for 'jasmine'. (2688)
Cannot find type definition file for 'jasminewd2'. (2688)
Cannot find type definition file for 'node'. (2688)
Cannot find type definition file for 'q'. (2688)
Cannot find type definition file for 'selenium-webdriver'. (2688)
server.ts (3,37): Cannot find module '@angular/platform-server'. (2307)
server.ts (4,32): Cannot find module '@angular/core'. (2307)
server.ts (6,26): Cannot find module 'express'. (2307)
server.ts (7,30): Cannot find module 'fs'. (2307)
server.ts (10,5): Cannot find name 'require'. (2304)
server.ts (17,21): Cannot find name '__dirname'. (2304)
server.ts (31,34): Cannot find name '__dirname'. (2304)
at getOutput 
(/home/ce0/Documents/Angular/exampleSSR/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:300:15)
at /home/ce0/Documents/Angular/exampleSSR/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:330:16
at Object.compile (/home/ce0/Documents/Angular/exampleSSR/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:489:17)
at Module.m._compile (/home/ce0/Documents/Angular/exampleSSR/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:382:43)
at Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/home/ce0/Documents/Angular/exampleSSR/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:385:12)
at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:690:10)
```

> package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "bulma": "^0.6.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.0"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
     "@angular/cli": "1.6.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.4.5",
    "webpack": "~2.4.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.1",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "postcss-url": "^5.1.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7"
  }
```

> tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
  "baseUrl": "src",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "declaration": false,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "target": "es5",
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "lib": [
    "es2016",
    "dom"
  ]
 }
}
```

So apparently stackoverflow complains my post is mostly code so i guess i have to write a bit more to allow me post the question, please bear with me. What could be the way out for such a situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, running Server-Side Rendering using `Angular Universal` to `Angular` is as simple as these 2 steps:

1. `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject {{ name of your project }}`
2. `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr`

Explanation about what each automatically created/modified file does has been perfectly explained here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-angular-universal

Comment: running 'ng add @nguniversal/........' shows up 
"Found compatible package version: @nguniversal/express-engine@14.0.3.
✔ Package information loaded.

The package @nguniversal/express-engine@14.0.3 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? (Y/n) " 
on entering y gives this 

" Packages successfully installed.
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"clientProject":"shopping-list-app","project":"shopping-list-app"}
Errors:

  Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(clientProject)."

Comment: @ImadUdDinKhan, I haven't worked with the latest nguniversal 14.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `ts-loader` in your dependencies

```
npm install --save ts-loader@3.5.0
```

Ideally you should follow the official documentation for setting up Angular Universal. It works:

https://angular.io/guide/universal

An working example [here](https://github.com/saptarshibasu/angular-universal-setup).